# What is the linux command to give execution permission of all files in current folder

Tags: linux, unix

Remember I need the command to change permissions of all files in current folder?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by "current" folder; if you mean the current folder (and all subfolders) then you could use `find` and `chmod` like so -

```
find . -type 'f' -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

If you mean the current folder (and no sub-folders) then you would use it like so -

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type 'f' -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

**OR** you could use `find` (possibly with `maxdepth`) and `xargs` likes so

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 chmod +x
```

**Note** that these commands will correctly handle files with spaces in the name and most other edge cases.

Comment: See warning for the second find: `find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.`

Comment: Should have you written `-maxdepth 1` ?

Comment: @skwllsp Yes. Yes I should have.

Comment: the current folder I mean is the directory in which I am , say user:A/B/C$  I want all the files in C to set new permission

Comment: I get message as find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter

Comment: @user3133745 It works here with no warnings or errors, but try `-type f` without the quotes.

Comment: Should I specify something as type. I tried 'type -f', I get find:unknown predicate '-type -f'

Comment: @user3133745 are you for real? `-type f`

Comment: what you mean by real -type f?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, by the way take a look at this message http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105330/17530 : `by using xargs, you do not have grep started for each and every file found`. You answer has the same problem - `chmod` is launched many times

Comment: @skwllsp Try using "xargs" when the filenames might have spaces (or dashes, or quotes). It isn't my idea of fun.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, no problem: `find . -print0 | xargs -0 chmod +x`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, `strace -f -e trace=execve bash -c 'find . -print0 | xargs -0 chmod +x'` and this is the system call:
`[pid  2111] execve("/bin/chmod", ["chmod", "+x", ".", "./HelloWorld.class", "./HelloWorld.java", "./Hello2.java", "./HelloWorld2.class", "./test file", "./test -- file"], [/* 35 vars */]) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Use `chmod` with a glob:

```
chmod +x *
```

(Technically that will give permission to list directories, too, but that shouldn't be a problem.)